# problem with spinner

Tags: android, spinner

what did I do wrong? My spinner was filled in, but I see only amount of lines, which corresponds the amount of data? But I didn't see the name of data.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[] { Manufacturer.colMarke }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    Spinner marke = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    marke.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: please ask your question right way, so viewer can answer your question.

Comment: could you provide how you build your cursor?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot ad _id column in your cursor or forgot to call:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

before

```
marke.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: there is a green button(check) for accepting an answer ... use it sometimes :)